# CLLocationManager stops in background

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have an app which uses `CLLocationManager` to track the user's route, drawing dots along the path taken. The app runs in the background using Required background modes > App registers for location updates.

As I understand, anything that happens in the background needs to be called from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` as this is the method that gets called with each location update.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes this stops getting called. It seems to happen when the user's location does not change much within the space of maybe 15 minutes or so. As far as I can tell, calls to `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` just stop, presumably to save the battery. Unfortunately, it doesn't resume again when you're back on the move.

I presume there's no way to override this behaviour, so I would like to use Notification Centre to inform the user that the app is no longer recording the route. The problem is, how can the app know that this has happened? If `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` is not called, I can't fire my notification. If it is being called, the notification should not fire.

Comment: I have this exact problem. When the user does not move for 15 minutes, and he starts moving again while keeping the app in background, locationManager:didUpdateLocations is not called. If the user put the app back in foreground, then locationManager:didUpdateLocations is called, but it does not contains all the previous locations between the time the user started moving and the time he put the app in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any way to be notified that the location manager has stopped sending you events, but there is a way to prevent it from happening.  In iOS 6, a new feature was added that allows the location manager to power down services if it doesn't think they are being used.  If you do the following, the location manager will continue sending you events in the background until you run out of battery:

> if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) 
>   {
>   self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
>   }

Also, in iOS6, you should be using `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` as `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated.

Comment: So location manager pauses location update when it detects that the user does not move. And when the user moves again, location manager resumes detection? But this is only when the app is in foreground. What about when the app is in background? In my experience, when location manager pauses, it does not resumes when the user starts moving again.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 delegate methods:

```
-(void)locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

and

```
-(void)locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

tells you when the location updates stop and start due to pausing.