# Alarm not working when device is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uilocalnotification

I want to trigger an alarm in my IOS device when the core location framework delegate method fires. The alarm rightly rings when the app is in the foreground. But when the device is locked, the alarm feature doesn't work. This is the code I have used.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];

localNotification.alertBody = @"body";
localNotification.soundName = @"RING.WAV";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Is it because I have used UILocalNotification class? If so, is there an alternative.

In the lock screen, the local notification alert body is displayed, but the alarm doesn't sound.

Edit:

In appdelegate I have the delegate to receive local notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/RING.WAV", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog(@"error :%@",[error description]);
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

I figured out that this method is not fired when the device is locked. Is there a way to trigger alarm based on UILocalNotification, when the device is locked?

Comment: is your app VoIP or audio? because when the device is locked the app it is stopped so it will never execute any code. You can execute the code before going to sleep and schedule a notification in the future.

Comment: But this works fine when the app is on foreground. Only when it locks, this issue occurs.

Comment: when and from where is your code called?

Comment: The above code gets called from CLLocationManager delegate method.

Comment: have you specified the background modes in the app-info.plist? Can you put a NSLog message before your code and have a look if the code is really executed?

Comment: Yes, in the background mode app plays audio or streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the audio session properties did the trick in this case.

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error: nil];
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the phone that your notification has an action

```
[localNotification setAlertAction:@"My Action"];
[localNotification setHasAction:YES];
```

Comment: I didn't post that part of the code, but actually I do set an action. And it doesn't work.

Comment: your fire date for the notification is set to go off immediately with your code written above. is that how it is in your app too? you can try this for your fireDate

`[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval://your time ahead of current date you want the notification to go off (try 10 for ten seconds) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];`

Comment: Shouldn't the same problem exists when app runs in the foreground too? In the foreground the app works just fine.

Comment: @alinoz is right about your app-info list. Have you looked at this answer? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16014814/3169550)

Comment: Default value of hasAction is true, so no need to set it if you haven't changed it.